# Add HTML inside Element reduce problems with escaping

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add HTML inside an element but I'm having serious problems escaping quotes and such.

I tried so many things and I'm not even getting the slashs, this is how it looks: (I removed any attempt of escaping because it was making it even more confusing)

```
document.getElementById("sharerContainer").innerHTML =
    "<div onclick='teleport('justwalk.it/house?uid=" + sharerID +
    "')'><div class='face' style='background-image: url('https://graph.facebook.com/" +
    sharerFID + "/picture');'></div>" + sharer;
```

Is there another way to write HTML through javascript to reduce this kind of problems?

Comment: Regular Expressions is all I can think of.

Comment: How about a [templating system](http://code.google.com/p/google-jstemplate/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("sharerContainer").innerHTML =
"<div onclick=\"teleport('justwalk.it/house?uid=" + sharerID +
"');\"><div class=\"face\" style=\"background-image: url('https://graph.facebook.com/" +
sharerFID + "/picture');\"></div>" + sharer;
```

Or you can try jQuery

Comment: You forgot to escape the ones around `style=`.

Comment: Yep, noticed that, and fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then use DOM manipulation (which you should prefer anyway):

```
var container = document.getElementById("sharerContainer");

var div = container.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.onclick = function() {
    teleport("justwalk.it/house?uid=" + encodeURIComponent(sharerID));
};

var inner_div = div.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
inner_div.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://graph.facebook.com/" + sharerFID + "/picture');";
inner_div.className = 'face';

div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sharer));
```

It's not clear what content these variables have so you probably have to tweak it a bit to make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do normal DOM manipulation, like so:

```
var sharerContainer = document.getElementById('sharerContainer');
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
var subDiv = document.createElement('div');
subDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sharer);
myDiv.appendChild(subDiv);
sharerContainer.appendChild(myDiv);

myDiv.onclick = function() {
    teleport('justwalk.it/house?uid=' + sharerID);
};
```

?

Comment: Because it's slower to execute and longer to write.

Comment: @MaxArt: If you could downvote comments... Anyway, it may be longer to write, but it 1) actually works and 2) is standards-compliant. `innerHTML` is a non-standard property, and who knows about the speed? By the time you'd escaped all of the things that need escaping, taking into account the fact that there is no perfect HTML-escaping solution for JavaScript out there and they almost all use regular expressions, it might actually be *faster*. By a lot.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a standard _de facto_, you can say _every_ browser supports it, even mobile browsers:
http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html
So, why do you bother so much about being standard?
As for the performance, the table is a bit old, but there's still no contest here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

Comment: @MaxArt: Yes, and that doesn't change the fact that it's still nonstandard. If you feel that you can properly escape an HTML string and make it faster than the standard DOM API, please be my guest and post it as an answer.

Comment: Developers should use `innerHTML` with a grain of salt, which means that it should be used only with 'reliable' strings, i.e. strings that the developer knows are correctly escaped. I think Liso22's example fits the case perfectly. Other cases may fit better with the DOM manipulation.
I still don't get the problem using a nonstandard property that is actually a standard, sorry.

Comment: @MaxArt: ... but the problem is that the strings *aren't* correctly escaped. Also, if it's nonstandard, it's *not a standard*. Sure, it's everywhere. But if you can avoid nonstandard properties, it's better to do so. What's more, the DOM API is designed so that you *don't make HTML syntax mistakes* - those break `innerHTML` entirely. The OP specifically asks: "Is there another way to write HTML through javascript to reduce this kind of problems?" and that's *exactly* what the DOM API is. If you don't want to take my word for it, take 95.2k-rep Felix Kling's.